# WinForms Custom Control: Why doesn't the arrow key raise the OnKeyDown event?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a dummy custom control. The entire source is at the bottom. If I place the control on an empty form (no weird things like key preview, etc, just the default, empty, untouched form), and press some keys, weirdly, arrow keys do not raise `OnKeyDown`. Why?

If I keep pressing 'A'.

```
Process: A
Key down: A
Process: A
Key down: A
Process: A
Key down: A
```

If I keep pressing the Space bar.

```
Process: Space
Key down: Space
Process: Space
Key down: Space
Process: Space
Key down: Space
Process: Space
```

If I keep pressing the Down arrow.

```
Process: Down
Process: Down
Process: Down
Process: Down
Process: Down
Process: Down
```

Is overriding the `ProcessCmdKey` the only and best way to handle arrow key inputs? I cannot use the `OnKeyUp` event, because it is raised only once, but users would keep pressing the arrow key to continuously scroll down, not just once when they release the arrow key.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        Debug.WriteLine("Key down: " + e.KeyCode);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        Debug.WriteLine("Key up: " + e.KeyCode);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process: " + keyData.ToString());
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the `Remarks` section of the [Control.KeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netcore-3.1) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding `ProcessCmdKey` I think is the right way to go here. I can't fully explain why `OnKeyDown` isn't being called, but there's nothing particularly wrong with overriding `ProcessCmdKey`, and if it works, it works.

Comment: Well, if there is no reason... Anyway, after posting this, I have found that I can use `OnPreviewKeyDown` too to get the continuous keydown event for the arrow key.